# Get timings with sign details and processing

Tags: python

I am having this details

```
[{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:11:00', 'sign': 7}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:12:00', 'sign': 7}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:13:00', 'sign': 7}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:14:00', 'sign': 8}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:15:00', 'sign': 8}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:16:00', 'sign': 8}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:17:00', 'sign': 8}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:18:00', 'sign': 9}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:19:00', 'sign': 9}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:20:00', 'sign': 9}, 
{'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:21:00', 'sign': 9}
```

I want to get a start and end time whenever there is a change in a sign like below

```
['1997-01-03 21:11:00 to 1997-01-03 21:13:00 => 7', '1997-01-03 21:14:00 to 1997-01-03 21:17:00 => 8', '1997-01-03 21:18:00 to 1997-01-03 21:21:00 => 9']
```

I have tried a lot of methods but not able to get these details. Can someone let me know what is the package or method to find this?

Comment: Hi! It appears that your problem is not quite clear. Could you provide a smaller input and the expected output for said input?

Comment: Edited my post with smaller input

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, perhaps could be improved, but it's easy to understand:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint


def my_func(data):
    data_dict = {}

    # Group by 'sign'
    for entry in data:
        if entry['sign'] not in data_dict:
            data_dict[entry['sign']] = []
        data_dict[entry['sign']].append(datetime.fromisoformat(entry['date_time']))

    # Order by date and return
    for sign in data_dict:
        data_dict[sign].sort()
        yield f'{data_dict[sign][0]} to {data_dict[sign][-1]} => {sign}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:11:00', 'sign': 7}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:12:00', 'sign': 7}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:13:00', 'sign': 7}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:14:00', 'sign': 8}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:15:00', 'sign': 8}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:16:00', 'sign': 8}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:17:00', 'sign': 8}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:18:00', 'sign': 9}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:19:00', 'sign': 9}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:20:00', 'sign': 9}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:21:00', 'sign': 9}
    ]

    pprint(list(my_func(data)))
```

Output:

```
[
    '1997-01-03 21:11:00 to 1997-01-03 21:13:00 => 7', 
    '1997-01-03 21:14:00 to 1997-01-03 21:17:00 => 8', 
    '1997-01-03 21:18:00 to 1997-01-03 21:21:00 => 9'
]
```

**Update** for Python 2.7

This fixes the problem but I think is not elegant enough due to the way sorting is done.

```
from datetime import datetime


def my_func(data):
    data_dict = {}

    # Group by 'sign'
    for entry in data:
        if entry['sign'] not in data_dict:
            data_dict[entry['sign']] = []
        data_dict[entry['sign']].append(datetime.strptime(entry['date_time'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    # Order by date and return
    for sign in data_dict:
        data_dict[sign].sort()

    return ['{} to {} => {}'.format(data_dict[sign][0], data_dict[sign][-1], sign) for sign in data_dict]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [
        {'date_time': '1998-01-03 21:11:00', 'sign': 7}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:12:00', 'sign': 7}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:13:00', 'sign': 7}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:14:00', 'sign': 8}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:15:00', 'sign': 8}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:16:00', 'sign': 8}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:17:00', 'sign': 8}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:18:00', 'sign': 9}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:19:00', 'sign': 9}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:20:00', 'sign': 9}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:21:00', 'sign': 9}
    ]

    print(list(my_func(data)))
```

Output:

```
['1997-01-03 21:14:00 to 1997-01-03 21:17:00 => 8', '1997-01-03 21:18:00 to 1997-01-03 21:21:00 => 9', '1997-01-03 21:12:00 to 1998-01-03 21:11:00 => 7']
```

Comment: Is there any way to replace yield f? because of python2.7

Comment: Please note I changed one of the dates to 1998 for the python2.7 example

Answer (score 0):

Here, I can call get_events(listOfDict,sign) and pass sign as 7,8,9 and then generate the output as dict

```
separated_sign_list=list()

def get_events(values, n):
    return filter( lambda d: d['sign'] == n , values)

for e in get_events(values,0):
    separated_sign_list.append(e)


interval_dict = {"dataSignInterval": separated_sign_list[0]['date_time'] + ' to ' +separated_sign_list[len(separated_sign_list)-1]['date_time'], "sign": separated_sign_list[0]['sign'] }

print(separated_sign_list)
print(interval_dict)
```

Comment: This shows Index error, when I assign values=[
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:11:00', 'sign': 7}, 
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:12:00', 'sign': 7}, ........,
        {'date_time': '1997-01-03 21:21:00', 'sign': 9}
    ]

Comment: what do you mean by index error? Have u tried calling the get_events(values, 7), u have to pass the sign values i.e. 7 / 8/9